# Is determining if a Turing machine runs in constant time decidable if one assumes it halts?

Tags: computability, time-complexity, undecidability, halting-problem

As the title states, is determining if a Turing machine runs in constant time decidable if one assumes it halts?

The decision problem, more formally:

Given a Turing machine $M$ where it is assumed it halts on all inputs, determine if it runs in $O(1)$ time.

Is this decidable?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "time complexity is independent of input"? Give a formal definition.

Comment: I realized my question was very poorly phrased so I have modified it significantly.

Comment: What does "$f = O(1)$" mean? What do you mean by *constant time*? Which machine model do you have in mind? Your question is still very much imprecise.

Comment: I have clarified my question further. Is it sufficiently precise now? If not, could you explain what is unclear about it?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the following version of the question:

> Can we decide whether an algorithm runs in constant time (that is, within $N$ steps, for some $N$), given that it is guaranteed to always halt?

This is not decidable. Given a Turing machine $T$, construct a new Turing machine $M$ which on input $t$ runs $T$ for up to $t$ steps. Then $M$ runs in constant time iff $T$ halts.

Answer (score 1):

It is still undecidable. Pick some algorithm M that has a time complexity dependent on the input (whatever exactly that means).

Now given some Turing machine T, consider the algorithm A that works as follows:

1) Simulate T on empty input until it halts.
2) Run M on the original input.

If T does not halt, then A never halts for any input, hence has time complexity independent of the input. If T halts after k steps, then A essentially takes k steps more than M does for any input. Since M's time complexity depends on the input, so should the time complexity of A.

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question was very poorly phrased so I have modified it significantly.